# Regexp to match [anypath]/ui/[anyfile].png

Tags: javascript, regex

I have set of image paths like these:

```
a/asstes/ui/img1.png
b/nested/source/ui/img.jpg
...
```

idea is that path to image and it's name can me random, but important parts are that image is inside `ui` folder and has extension of `jpg` or `png`.

What regex can I use to check filepath for these conditions?

Thus far I got to this point `/\ui\/img1\.(png|jpg)$/` this matches `a/asstes/ui/img1.png` correctly, but ideally `img1` should be dynamic as file name can be anything.

**EDIT** ideally it will match images that are directly under `/ui`

Comment: Just replace `img1` with `.+?`

Comment: @Toto does the trick thank you. What does `?` add? I can see it works with `.+` on its own as well. This also matches nested images, ideally image should be matched directly under ui as mentioned above

Comment: `/\ui\/.*\.+(png|jpg)$/`
Just adding `.+` matches any thing one or more times

Comment: @ShankarRegmi I just added edit to the question. Is it possible to modify this to satisfy that requirement? Only match images directly under `/ui` folder not nested ones

Comment: `/\/ui\/[^.]+\.(png|jpg)$/i` will be more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `/ui/` have to be the last directory, use:

```js
var test = [
    'a/asstes/ui/img1.png',
    'b/nested/source/ui/img.jpg',
    'b/nested/ui/source/img.png',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/\/ui\/[^\/]+\.(png|jpg)$/.test(a);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `/\w+\/ui\/\w+\.\jpg|png$/`

The *$* is make you always input a jpg or a png at the final of the path.

Comment: You should try before posting an answer.

Comment: Are you sure? Test with `/my dir-1/ui/my img-file.png` or `abc/ui/img.png` (that must match) and `/abc/ui/png` (that must not)

Answer (score -1):

JS regex for image paths:

```
/(.*\/.*)+\.(png|jpg)$/
```

Your case:

```
/(.*\/.*)+ui\/.*(png|jpg)$/
```

Comment: `(.*\/.*)+` or `(.*\/.*)+` is a [straight road](https://regex101.com/r/7MClSK/1) to catastrophic backtracking.